# Unable to list kafka topics in openwhisk setup

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, openwhisk

Setup details: 
I am setting up openwhisk on my local ubuntu(16.04) vm. in this setup kafka is running in one docker and zookeeper in another docker.

I connect to the the kafka docker using cmd

```
sudo docker exec -it <container id> sh
```

once connected i execute the following command to get the list of topics

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181
```

which gives me an exception

```
Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 7203; nested exception is:
        java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

i am unable to understand why is it trying to use 7203 port?

docker ps output

```
83eba3961247        ches/kafka:0.10.0.1              "/start.sh"              
11 days ago         Up 23 hours         7203/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9092->9092/tcp                                                                                                                       
kafka
947fa689a7ef        zookeeper:3.4                    "/docker-
entrypoin..."   11 days ago         Up 23 hours         2888/tcp, 
0.0.0.0:2181->2181/tcp, 3888/tcp                                                                                                             zookeeper
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The [Kafka container OpenWhisk is using](https://hub.docker.com/r/ches/kafka/) sets a `JMX_PORT` by default. That's the 7203 port you're seeing. To get your script to work you need to unset that environment setting:

```
unset JMX_PORT; bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181
```

Note though, that `localhost` is not a valid address for your zookeeper instance, as it refers to the localhost of the current container, which is not Zookeeper. If you exchange `localhost` with the external IP of your VM or the IP of the zookeeper container (get it via `docker inspect zookeeper --format {{.NetworkSettings.Networks.bridge.IPAddress}}`) your topics should be listed fine.

Comment: Thanks it worked. one more ques will this unsetting of the JMX_PORT will impact the working of the openwhisk setup in any way?

Comment: No it won't. It's only relevant for your single call anyway and the setup as it stands in OpenWhisk does not use JMX from Kafka at all.

Comment: echo $JMX_PORT : To check what is port no used by JMX. export JMX_PORT=NEW_PORT_NUMBER : to assign new port no.